# Retrofit manage No objects model list JSON

Tags: json, rest, error-handling, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit lib to get objects from JSON Api Rest Service I implemented, simple query and echo in PHP.

This is JSON I usually use to create objects in my Android APP:

```
[  
   {  
      "event_id":"1",
      "event_name":"Lungo il tevere",
      "event_image_url":"https:\/\/www.dayroma.it\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/06\/event_fb-9400.jpg",
      "event_content":"Lungo il Tevere Roma 2016, bancarelle sulle banchine del Tevere",
      "event_owner":"1",
      "event_start_time":"22:00:00",
      "event_end_time":"03:00:00",
      "event_all_day":"0",
      "event_start_date":"2016-07-05",
      "event_end_date":"2016-07-06",
      "location_name":"Lungotevere",
      "location_owner":"1",
      "location_address":"Piazza Navona 2",
      "location_town":"Roma",
      "location_state":null,
      "location_postcode":null,
      "location_region":null,
      "location_country":"IT",
      "location_latitude":"41.897785",
      "location_longitude":"12.472971"
   },
   {  
      "event_id":"3",
      "event_name":"Black Mountain + Soviet Soviet",
      "event_image_url":"https:\/\/www.dayroma.it\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/timthumb.jpeg",
      "event_content":"Affrontare la psichedelia granitica dei Black Mountain",
      "event_owner":"1",
      "event_start_time":"20:00:00",
      "event_end_time":"00:00:00",
      "event_all_day":"0",
      "event_start_date":"2016-07-05",
      "event_end_date":"2016-07-06",
      "location_name":"Villa Ada",
      "location_owner":"1",
      "location_address":"Villa Ada ",
      "location_town":"Roma",
      "location_state":null,
      "location_postcode":null,
      "location_region":null,
      "location_country":"IT",
      "location_latitude":"41.932831",
      "location_longitude":"12.501247"
   },
   {  
      "event_id":"7",
      "event_name":"test 4",
      "event_image_url":"",
      "event_content":"05test 4",
      "event_owner":"1",
      "event_start_time":"01:00:00",
      "event_end_time":"05:00:00",
      "event_all_day":"0",
      "event_start_date":"2016-07-06",
      "event_end_date":"2016-07-06",
      "location_name":"Villa Ada",
      "location_owner":"1",
      "location_address":"Villa Ada ",
      "location_town":"Roma",
      "location_state":null,
      "location_postcode":null,
      "location_region":null,
      "location_country":"IT",
      "location_latitude":"41.932831",
      "location_longitude":"12.501247"
   }
]
```

I need to manage errors and JSON like this, if the objects list is empty:

```
[  
   {  
      "status":"0",
      "message":"No Event"
   }
]
```

For the implementation I used this
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

At the moment, if is there no events ( the object model ), I retrive a 200 response code and that json.
How can I manage this scenario? Have I to change Api Rest Response to give me a 404 or 400 and then manage the error?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using object model use Response body in your method

Example in retrofit 2.x

```
 public interface RequestService{
    @GET("/users/{user}")
    Call<ResponseBody> getLogin(@Field("userId") String, @Field("password") String);
}
```

In your activity

```
RequestService service = retrofit.create(RequestService.class);
Call<ResponseBody> result = service.getLogin(username,password);
result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    try {
        System.out.println(response.body().string());//Parse your json here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
});
```

Comment: Sorry SaravInfern, I'm doing in that way, but when I get json "message":"No Event"  onResponse function is ok and I get an event list with only one object with all field null... All because response code is 200 even if there's no events... I tried to change response code, but nothing...I'm using json api plugin wordpress and a custom controller... Do you know how can I create a custom api rest ?

Comment: I cant understand you please be clear, What is the problem you are face? did you debug the call with break point??

Comment: If I retrieve the json with "No Events", in onReponse callback it's created an event list with only one element with all field null, this causes a nullPoint Breakpoint. I have to switch response 200 in onResponse if the json is full of elements or not, in both case my api rest retrieve a 200 response: if there are elements, arraylist of objects is correclty filled, if not, arraylist have only an element with null field, this is very frustrating.